# How to architect a video site, from a performance point of view

Tags: asp.net, performance, video, high-traffic

I want to build a high traffic video site, which has many videos and visitors, using ASP.NET. But I have no experience of high traffic sites and video sites.

Anyone can give me some stuff to read or some keywords for me to google? In the performance point of view.

Many thanks :)

**UPDATE:** I said our site is similar to Youtube, but that just meant that the site structure would be similar to Youtube. We won't have that high traffic. So I delete that sentence, sorry for confusing you :)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it's hard to imagine that you could both ask this question and be remotely capable of building a site that could scale to youtube levels of traffic.

The good news is that that's OK. Youtube got huge fast because there were very few sites like it at the time. Your site won't get that big that fast. You'll have time to play with the variables, and if you get big enough to challenge youtube you'll be able to hire people to help you optimize things.

What you ought to be worried about is "How am I going to pay for the bandwidth my video site is going to incur?"

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I mean the site stucture is similar to Youbut. But it won'have that high traffic. :)

Comment: Are there some stuffs on architecting high traffic video sites for me to read? Some keywords are also ok. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture (pretty extensive list)

http://www.taranfx.com/what-powers-youtube

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what you mean with performance and where you see potential issues with it. There is the perfomance of the website in general where a video hosting site is not much different then any other site. There is the frontend performance, etc.

Where a video hosting site is different to most other sites is the ammount of data to be transfered and the performance for video rendering. Means probably the first wall to hit is the bandwith of ones webserver (if you would be starting with one standard machine) or the CPU going mad.

-> First step would be to seperate website from video delivery and encoding to be able to scale.

Now I don't know about ASP.NET but with Drupal there are many people who have done similar sites to youtube [1] and there are many contrib modules [2] to support also above mentioned tasks like Media Mover [3]. Might give you a starting point.

[1] http://www.google.com/search?&q=drupal+youtube+clone

[2] http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid%3A67

[3] http://drupal.org/project/media_mover